# Edge Extension: get current tab url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge

I'am trying to port a chrome extension to microsoft edge with the microsoft edge extension toolkit.

In my extension i must get the current tab url, to perform an api call.

so in chrome and firefox i use this code in a browser_action:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  // print object for debugging
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tabs[0]));

  // get active tab url
  var activeTab = tabs[0];
  var activeTabURL = activeTab.url;
  document.getElementById("input").value = activeTabURL;
});
```

In Edge the url is not in this object and i cant find anything in there documentation. Can anyone tell me how to get the url in edge?

Comment: I don't know about Edge but in Chrome the `url` property is present only if you have `"tabs"` in "permissions" in manifest.json along with a matching URL pattern or "activeTab".

Comment: thats right...in chrome and firefox my code is working and the "activeTab" permission in manifest.json is set ;-)

Comment: Quick googling shows activeTab doesn't seem to be supported in Edge.

Comment: as i write in my question, i know it and searching a way how to get the url in edge

Comment: No, you didn't write you know it, but by a simple exclusion the only way is to have "tabs" and a matching URL pattern in "permissions" (or "optional_permissions" if Edge supports it).

Comment: ok, the problem was really that "activeTabs" is not supported...replaced it with "tabs" in permissions and the code from my question works... a matching url pattern in "permissions" is not needed. thanks!

Comment: @ Tobias, From your last comment. I can see that you had solved your issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and mark it as an answer will help other community members in future for similar kind of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, it was established that the original extension used `"activeTab"` permission to gain access to the active tab's details without broad permissions.

Since it's [not supported by Edge (yet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-manifest-keys#supported-permissions), you effectively don't have permissions to the tabs' details (as this is sensitive data), you need to fall back to having broad permissions.

Declaring `"tabs"` permission will be sufficient to get the URL of any open tab.